# Unbiased estimation of the mean of a normal distribution when the parameter space is restricted

Tags: self-study, estimation

Let $X_1, . . . , X_n$ be an iid sample from $\text{N}(\theta,\sigma^2)$, in which $\sigma^2$ is known and $\theta$ can have the values $0,±1,±2, . . .$,  and let $\bar{X}_n^*=\max\{k\in\mathbb{Z}:k\leq \bar{X}_n\}$ be the largest integer smaller or equal than $\bar{X}_n$.

1. Show that $\bar{X}_n^*$ is an unbiased estimator for the restricted parameter $\theta$. That is, prove that $\text{E}_\theta\left[\bar{X}_n^*\right]=\theta$, for every integer $\theta$.
2. There exist positive constants $a$ and $b$ such that, for all sufficiently large $n$, $\text{Var}_\theta\left[\bar{X}_n^*\right] \leq a\cdot e^{−b\,n}$, for every integer $θ$.

Comment: -1 because you don't state what you have tried to answer the question, nor given any indication of where you're having trouble.

Answer (score 1):

The first assertion does not seem right, but maybe I am wrong (in which case I hope somebody wiser jumps in and proves it).
The estimator $\bar{X}_n^*$ is the floor function of $\bar X_n$, $\bar{X}_n^*=\lfloor \bar X_n \rfloor$ and we have that 
$$\lfloor \bar X_n \rfloor = \bar X_n - \{\bar X_n\}$$

Where $\{\bar X_n\}$ is the fractional part, $0\le\{\bar X_n\} <1$.

Then 
$$E (\bar{X}_n^*) = E(\lfloor \bar X_n \rfloor) = E(\bar X_n - \{\bar X_n\}) = \theta - E(\{\bar X_n\}) $$

But since $0\le\{\bar X_n\} <1$, It does not seem possible to have $E(\{\bar X_n\}) =0$ so as to establish unbiasedness, since $n$ remains finite... It looks like the floor function could only be asymptotically unbiased... Any comments?